# What is this "recumbent" trainer?

Tags: trainer, history, track-racing

In the photo below, what is the trainer that is attached to the bike?  Are these custom fab?

[image: spinning device]

Comment: What is it?  It's weird!

Comment: It's made by Cinelli.  Still looking for more info when I find time.

Comment: All I can say is that guy looks silly as hell wearing full road kit laying down with a weird trainer.  A pair of old shorts and t-shirt would have done just fine without dirtying expensive bike clothes.

Comment: @CareyGregory He looks as if he is a sponsored track athlete, so he probably doesn't even need to wash his stuff himself, so why not take the additional comfort from the correct clothes? Also: This blanket is most beautiful. I stole a similar one from my granny a while back...

Comment: A Cinelli sponsored athlete using a Cinelli manufactured  home trainer while wearing full kit with Cinelli all over it. I'd suggest this is some sort of promo photo or interview.

Comment: It does look a bit like a 'creeper' used for sliding under cars to do mechanic work, with a custom frame bolted on.

Comment: Maybe just a case study? cinelli is a company that knows how to weld steel elements toigether. probably only took them a few hours to put that thing together. No idea who did build the guy using it but it could just be the guy working at the next door restaurant who did it for the banter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The guy using it apparently is [Hans-Henrik Oersted](http://prollyisnotprobably.com/2014/01/cinelli-and-hans-henrik-oersted/) who was sponsered by chinelli. The company recently did a rerun of two jerseys to honor him.
The picture can also be found on [cinellis website about the jerseys](http://www.wingedstore.com/news/17-cinelli-x-hans-henrik-oersted) so i wrote a request for information to their customer service.
They answered it is a handmade trainer build especially for Hans-Henrik Oersted in the 80's. It was never for sale.